# Animate div from center to left on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, css-transitions

I have created a layout and I am stuck with the animation part, as it can be seen here in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/77q81gz9/), If you click on any boxes from center then the same navigation on left side show with vertical layout, and center blocks will hide, this is working fine but requirement is when click on any of the centered boxes, it should show the left navigation but its show a animation that all those centered navigation are moving to left one by one.

Currently its working with simple show and hide but I want to add animation that will show the box moving from center position to left position, can somebody please help with the animation or guide how to achieve that?

Here are the code of what I have created so far:

```
<style>
  .noPad{padding:0;}
  .row {border-bottom: 1px solid #444;}
  .col_box {border-right: 1px solid #444;}
  .content_box{background:#f0f0f0; text-align:center; color:#000; font-size:18px; height:200px; display:block; width:100%; line-height:200px; cursor:pointer;}
  .content_box:hover{background:#CCC;}
  .sidenav {left: 0; position: fixed; top: 0;   z-index: 1; font-size: 18px; background:#f0f0f0; width:320px; height:100%; display:none;}
  .sidenav  ul{list-style:none; padding:0; margin:0;}
  .sidenav  ul > h2{font-size:18px; color:#960000; text-transform:uppercase; text-align:center;}
  .sidenav  ul li{list-style:none;}
  .sidenav  ul li a{text-decoration:none; color:#404040; display:block; padding:15px 0 15px 25px; border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(".content_box").click(function(){
    $(".sidenav").show();
    $(".main-wrapper").hide();
    });
 </script>
 <div class="sidenav">
  <ul>
  <h2>Navigation Here</h2>
   <li><a href="#">Navigation 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Navigation 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Navigation 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Navigation 4</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Navigation 5</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Navigation 6</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Navigation 7</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Navigation 8</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
<div class="container-fluid main-wrapper">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2 col_box noPad">
  <div class="content_box">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col_box noPad">
  <div class="content_box">  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col_box noPad">
  <div class="content_box"> Navigation 1 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col_box noPad">
  <div class="content_box">  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col_box noPad">
  <div class="content_box"> Navigation 2 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col_box noPad">
  <div class="content_box">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2 col_box noPad">
  <div class="content_box">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col_box noPad">
  <div class="content_box"> Navigation 3 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col_box noPad">
  <div class="content_box">  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col_box noPad">
  <div class="content_box"> Navigation 4</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col_box noPad">
  <div class="content_box"> </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col_box noPad">
  <div class="content_box">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2 col_box noPad">
  <div class="content_box">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col_box noPad">
  <div class="content_box"> </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col_box noPad">
  <div class="content_box">  Navigation 5 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col_box noPad">
  <div class="content_box"> </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col_box noPad">
  <div class="content_box"> Navigation 6</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col_box noPad">
  <div class="content_box">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2 col_box noPad">
  <div class="content_box">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col_box noPad">
  <div class="content_box"> Navigation 7 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col_box noPad">
  <div class="content_box">  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col_box noPad">
  <div class="content_box"> Navigation 8</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col_box noPad">
  <div class="content_box">  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col_box noPad">
  <div class="content_box">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to animate the display property, which is what jQuerys show/hide functions toggle. In stead, you can animate the menu by positioning it outside the canvas (`left: -320px`) and setting the position to `left: 0` on click, then add a transition to your liking. Something along these lines (I edited the code from your fiddle).

Edit: Oh, wait, I think I kind of misunderstood how you wanted to animate. I've edited my answer slightly to animate the centered box as well.

```js
$(".content_box").click(function(){
 $(".sidenav").css("left", "0");
 $(".col_box").css("margin-left", "-100%");
});
```

```css
.noPad{padding:0;}
.row {border-bottom: 1px solid #444;}
.col_box {
  border-right: 1px solid #444;
  width: 100%;
}
.col_box:nth-child(1) {
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
}
.col_box:nth-child(2) {
  transition: all .2s ease-in .2s;
}
.col_box:nth-child(3) {
  transition: all .2s ease-in .4s;
}
.content_box{background:#f0f0f0; text-align:center; color:#000; font-size:18px; height:200px; display:block; width:100%; line-height:200px; cursor:pointer;}
.content_box:hover{background:#CCC;}
.sidenav {
  left: -320px;
  transition: all .2s ease-in .6s;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 18px;
  background:#f0f0f0;
  width:320px;
  height:100%;
}
.sidenav  ul{list-style:none; padding:0; margin:0;}
.sidenav  ul > h2{font-size:18px; color:#960000; text-transform:uppercase; text-align:center;}
.sidenav  ul li{list-style:none;}
.sidenav  ul li a{text-decoration:none; color:#404040; display:block; padding:15px 0 15px 25px; border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;}
```

```html
<div class="sidenav">
 <ul>
    <h2>Navigation Here</h2>
    <li><a href="#">Navigation 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Navigation 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Navigation 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Navigation 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Navigation 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Navigation 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Navigation 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Navigation 8</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid main-wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col_box noPad">
      <div class="content_box"> Navigation 1 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col_box noPad">
      <div class="content_box"> Navigation 2 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col_box noPad">
      <div class="content_box"> Navigation 3 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it works almost similar, but I was looking to move each boxes one by one, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can add a fourth value to the transition property, setting a timeout for the animation, like this: `transition: all .2s ease-in .4s;`. In order to animate different elements in a given order, the `.4s` needs to be changed for each element. I've updated my answer again to reflect this. Now, the first `.col_box` transitions immediately, the second after .2s, and so on. In the end I added the delays up to calculate the delay for transitioning `.sidenav` back in, e.g. .6s. I deleted a bunch of your nodes to illustrate the example, but you get the idea. :)

Comment: It's also possible to do it by using jQuerys `setTimeout `, should you prefer that.

Comment: I think setTimeout would be good idea, will give a try. thanks!